# how to generate random content of random size and appending to a file?

Tags: linux

so using the terminal in Linux i need to add text to a file that is completely random and of random size the only ways i can find are using

$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc "\t\n [:alnum:]" | head -c1000 > file.txt

which is of a specific size is there away to make it a random size as well, very very new to Linux any advice will be well received.

Comment: There is no uniform probability distribution on the set of natural numbers. You need some non-uniform distribution. What should it be? E.g. `$RANDOM` in Bash will give you at most `32767`. `$((RANDOM*RANDOM))` will extend the range to this number squared, but many natural numbers smaller than that will be impossible to get.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kamil Maciorowski points out, your problem as posited lacks any bounds on what 'random size' means.  Random between 0 and infinity?  You probably don't have enough disk space for that.  Random between 0 and the total free space remaining on your drive?  That could be done, but you probably won't have enough disk space **after** a few iterations of that.

Further, like all forms of perfection, perfect or "complete" randomness is difficult to achieve.  I'm not qualified to say how close this comes to achieving the goal of being "completely random."  But assuming that you want a pseudo-randomly-sized pseudo-random assortment of the 96 printable ASCII characters (if you consider <kbd>RUBOUT</kbd> printable), consider this solution:

Set the variable `max_size` to the largest number of bytes of random text you want in one iteration.  I'll use an example of 1 Megabyte, but you can set it to whatever you like.  Then use that value to scale a fractional random number to a random number of bytes.  Add .5 to round to the nearest integer, and discard the decimal point and any trailing digits.

```
max_size=1048576
text_size=$(bc <<< "scale=6; $RANDOM/32767*$max_size+.5")
text_size="${text_size%.*}"
```

Now read from `/dev/random`, use `tr` to delete characters outside your desired range, and pipe it to `head` to trim the output to the desired number of bytes:

```
$ tr -d '\000-\037,\200-\377' < /dev/random | head -c $text_size > rand.txt
```

In practice:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
max_size=1048576
text_size=$(bc <<< "scale=6; $RANDOM/32767*$max_size+.5")
text_size="${text_size%.*}"
echo $text_size
tr -d '\000-\037,\200-\377' < /dev/random | head -c $text_size > rand.txt
ls -l rand.txt
$ ./foo.sh
541168
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  541168 Aug  5 15:43 rand.txt
$ ./foo.sh
13888
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  13888 Aug  5 15:43 rand.txt
$ ./foo.sh
644659
-rw-------  1 jim  jim  644659 Aug  5 15:43 rand.txt
```